# How to join next row in Cloud Spanner

Tags: join, google-cloud-platform, row-number, google-cloud-spanner

How to join left next row in Cloud Spanner.

I want to calculate how many kilometers driven each driver.

My table looks like:

```
vehicle_id | driver_id | odometer
```

```
     1     |      1    |     10  
     1     |      1    |     20  
     1     |      2    |     20  
     1     |      2    |     40  
     1     |      1    |     40  
     1     |      1    |     50  
     2     |      1    |     10  
     2     |      1    |     20  
     2     |      2    |     20  
     2     |      2    |     30  
     2     |      1    |     30 
     2     |      1    |     80 
     2     |      2    |     80 
     2     |      2    |     120
```

Results should be:

```
 driver_id | total_mileage
```

```
      1    |     80  
      2    |     70
```

My solution is:

```
 SUM (mileage) 
 FROM (SELECT (odometer2-odometer) AS mileage
       FROM (SELECT vehicle_id , odometer ,driver_id , 
             NEXT.driver_id AS driver_id 2, NEXT.odometer AS odometer2  FROM Table

             **JOIN NEXT ROW** AS NEXT

             )
       WHERE driver_id=driver_id2
       )
 GROUP BY driver_id
```

```
vehicle_id | driver_id | odometer | driver_id2 | odometer2 |mileage
```

```
     1     |      1    |     10   |      1    |     20    |   10  
     1     |      1    |     20   |      2    |     20    |   - 
     1     |      2    |     20   |      2    |     40    |   20 
     1     |      2    |     40   |      1    |     40    |   - 
     1     |      1    |     40   |      1    |     50    |   10 
     1     |      1    |     50   |     -     |     -     |   -    
     2     |      1    |     10   |      1    |     20    |   10  
     2     |      1    |     20   |      2    |     20    |   - 
     2     |      2    |     20   |      2    |     30    |   10 
     2     |      2    |     30   |      1    |     30    |   - 
     2     |      1    |     30   |      1    |     80    |   50 
     2     |      1    |     80   |      2    |     80    |   - 
     2     |      2    |     80   |      2    |     120   |   40 
     2     |      2    |     120  |     -     |     -     |   -
```

In Cloud Spanner function Row_number, OVER, LAG do not exist. 
My question is how to join left next row in Cloud Spanner?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to PIVOT the data.  This is not something that is doable directly in [Cloud Spanner SQL](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/query-syntax) - you'll need to post-process the data to affect the pivot.

Comment: Originally said "not possible directly in SQL" -- which is true for just about any SQL variant.  Except for MSSQL.